# Reduction in size of array when passed to a function

Tags: c, parameter-passing, sizeof

This code takes input from user and simply stores them in an array.The array is then passed to a function and then printed out.The problem is that when I check the size of array in main() and then in function() they are different.Please check the output image link I provided to clearly understand what I am saying. The size of int is 4 bytes. Dev-C++ is IDE used which uses TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64 bit compiler.Can someone clarify what is going on here?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int function(int formal[]);
    main()
    {
        int input[10],loop,limit;
        printf("Enter limit:");
        scanf("%d",&limit);
        for(loop=0;loop<limit;loop++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&input[loop]);
        }
        printf("Size of input array:%d\t",sizeof(input));
        function(input);
    }
    int function(int formal[])
    {
        int loop;
        printf("Size of parameter array:%d\n",sizeof(formal));
        for(loop=0;loop<5;loop++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",formal[loop]);
        }
    }
```

output:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqHiS.png